# Ajax with Promise Object is blocking UI Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I am creating one Login form and for my application I have created a service call object below

```
Util.postServiceCall = function(url, formData, handlerDone, handlerAlways, handlerFail, context, preventLoader) {
    handlerDone = typeof handlerDone === 'function' ? handlerDone : function() {};
    handlerAlways = typeof handlerAlways === 'function' ? handlerAlways : function() {};
    handlerFail = typeof handlerFail === 'function' ? handlerFail : function() {};
    var hostname = Util.sStorage('get', 'hostname');
    if (hostname && hostname !== 'undefined' && hostname !== 'null') {
        REST_ROOT_URL = window.location.protocol + '//' + JSON.parse(hostname) + Util.getContextPath() + '/rest';
    }
    var promise = $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            crossDomain: true,
            url: REST_ROOT_URL + url,
            data: JSON.stringify(formData)
        })
        .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {})
        .always(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {})
        .fail(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {});

    return promise;
};
```

When I need to call any services, I call this method.

```
Util.postServiceCall('/test/login',{},function(data){
});
```

But when I am getting an UNAUTHORIZED Error , in the page the form elements are blocked and can not able to type anything in input boxes neither able to clean that.

If I direct use the AJAX call like this

```
 $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            crossDomain: true,
            url: REST_ROOT_URL + url,
            data: JSON.stringify(formData)
        })
        .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {})
        .always(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {})
        .fail(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {});
```

then THE UI elements are not blocked.

I am strange why this behavior are different.

Comment: Is `REST_ROOT_URL` defined at each call to `Util.postServiceCall()`?

Comment: Any chance your `Util.sStorage` or `Util.getContextPath()` have something to do with it?

Comment: No all have their Values.. REST_ROOT_URL is a global constant reassign in Util.postServiceCall()